# What value specify to creating new connection on MySql workbench

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-workbench

i have installed MySql workbench. i want to create a database in MySql.
when i click New connection, it open a dialog, there are following default values:
- in connection method: there are combo box having three values:
    Standard (TCP/IP)
    Local Socket/Pipe
    Standard TCP/IP over SSH

- Hostname: 127.0.0.1
- Port: 3306
- Username: root
- Password:
- Default Schema:

what values i fill to creating a new connection.
i want to use database at local and want to use this with a java hibernate program.

please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You have to select **Standard (TCP/IP)**

- Hostname: 127.0.0.1
- Port: 3306
- Username: root
- Password : root_password
- Default Schema : database_you_want_to_connect_to

See this image for example [image]
<sub>(source: [mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/images/wb-manage-db-connections-dialog.png))</sub>

Comment: Rakesh Ji as u specfied, i have tried. when i click to test connection, it give error- Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (10061)

Comment: @user783160, check if the root password is correctly entered, and try changing the hostname ip to "localhost". First try connection on the command line with the username as root and the password the one which you are using. command --> mysql -u root -p

Comment: Rakesh Ji, i have MySQL Workbench 5.2 CE. i am not able to creating a new connection. i have no remember what i set the password when i installed MySQL Workbench.
although a database is exist which i use some times. but i am not able to create a new connection on localhost.
when i try to create a new connection on local host. it show error
Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (10061)

please help.

Comment: @user783160, if you don't remember the password for your mysql database, then you cant connect it at all. Try resetting the password, [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html#resetting-permissions-windows)

Comment: I have a slightly different problem.  I've put in these parameters, the root password is blank.  In MySQL Workbench, I can-right click on this connection, select "Start Command Line Client", and it connects without problem.  But if I double click on this connection, I just get the "Opening SQL Editor.. please stand by" window, and it doesn't go away.    If I connect to the MySQL database on my GoDaddy hosting account... no problem, it connects and works fine.  What am I missing on my localhost db ...?